# mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using a prepared statement I have passed exactly the same amount of variable in bind_param as I am expecting but still it is giving me an error of variable count doesn't match.

```
$query = "select `shipping_name`,`shipping_address1`,`shipping_address12`,`shipping_city`,`shipping_state`,`shipping_postalcode`,`billing_name`,`billing_address2`,`billing_address22`,`billing_city`,`billing_state`,`billing_postalcode` from puppy_shipping where unique_id=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$bind = 'ssssssssssss';
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($bind, $shipping_name, $shipping_address1, $shipping_address12, $shipping_city, $shipping_state, $shipping_postalcode, $billing_name, $billing_address2, $billing_address22, $billing_city, $billing_state, $billing_postalcode);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: `bind_result()` doesn't have binding of types (like `bind_param()` does), so drop the `$bind` variable.

Comment: done! now i have this error!  Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in

Comment: and it looks like this now! $stmt->bind_result('ssssssssssss',$shipping_name,$shipping_address1,$shipping_address12,$shipping_city,$shipping_state,$shipping_postalcode,$billing_name,$billing_address2,$billing_address22,$billing_city,$billing_state,$billing_postalcode);

Comment: Like I said, `bind_result()` doesn't need binding of types - all the parameters are the values you selected, nothing more. Look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: lol,my bad its done thanks it was new to me so i made a mistake

Comment: you could write your answer in separate comment so  i can mark it as correct for other people help

Comment: Done! *Cheers* ;-) @uneeb

Comment: @Qirel thanks man :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this line

```
$stmt->bind_result($bind, $shipping_name,$shipping_address1,$shipping_address12, ....);
```

You're trying to bind the variable-types, like you do with `bind_param()`, which is wrong - because this function does not have a parameter like that. `bind_result()`s only arguments are the values you select from the query, nothing else.

The solution is to simply remove `$bind` from your `bind_result()` call, making it

```
$stmt->bind_result($shipping_name, $shipping_address1, $shipping_address12, ....);
```

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented style

```
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code);
```

Procedural style

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $code);
```